# Cython - setup.py for c++ file with dependencies

Tags: python, c++, cython, setup.py

I have some C++ code that I'd like to call from python. Until now I had all my C++ code in one file and had one `.pyx` file corresponding to that code. So lets say my C++ file `test_A.cpp` looks like this

```
struct test{
float x;
}
```

and in my `test_A.pyx` file I have

```
cdef extern from "test_A.cpp"
    cdef cppstruct test:
         float x
```

and my `setup.py` file looks like

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

extensions = [Extension("test_A", ["test_A.pyx"],
              include_dirs=[np.get_include()],
              extra_compile_args=["-std=c++11"],
              extra_link_args=[],
              language="c++")]

setup(ext_modules = cythonize(extensions))
```

This works as it should, but now I want to split up my file for better readability and I cannot figure out how to compile the code. Say now I have a second file `test_B.cpp` that I include in `test_A.cpp`

```
#include "test_B.h"

struct test{
test x;
test_B y;
}
```

how do I now have to modify my `setup.py` file such that it compiles `test_A.cpp` but then also compiles and links `test_B.cpp` and all functions called from `test_a.cpp`? Do I have to write a second `.pyx` file for `test_B.cpp`?

Thanks

Comment: Assuming there isn't a single header to include all the symbols from, yes, you need to separately wrap each file.

Comment: Instead of `#include "test_B.h"` I now wrote `#include "test_B.cpp"` and it works like this. I don't really know why, maybe I need to learn a bit more about compiling C++ in general.

Comment: There are two "main" ways to link to external code in Cython. 1: make a library out of it, include the link and include flags, and wrap it in Cython. 2: list explicitly the file, as you do (and wrap of course is still needed). With only the headers (as you do), you can normally build but not link the final ".so" file, except if it's a header-only code.